# ZeroClipboard/zlip causing Unsafe Javascript warnings in iframe

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, zeroclipboard

I'm using zClip: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/  (and tried ZeroClipboard also with same result)

When I used it from within an iframe I get this javascript error/warning:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file://localhost/Users/me/Desktop/test.html from frame with URL http://localhost:3000/a. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'file'. Protocols must match.
```

file://localhost/Users/me/Desktop/test.html is a local file I setup with an iframe in it which loads my widget.  The copy button is in the widget.

The copy functionality seems to work perfectly despite the error, so I'm not sure why it is there and would like to clean it up.

This is my coffee/javascript in the widget:

```
  btn = $('#'+id)
  btn.zclip
    path: '/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: btn.data('copy')
```

Which is just the standard stuff.  When I comment the `btn.zlip` block the error goes away so it seems to be that line.

I assume there is something in the zeroclip javascript which is bubbling up outside the iframe to the parent but I can't find anything offhand.  Was wondering if anyone else solved this.  Thanks!

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8041009/151365

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a flash object is embedded in a cross-domain iframe, it will throw an cross-domain exception.

For example, check out this jsfiddle with an iFrame embedded: http://jsfiddle.net/bkCdB/

```
<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/6V_DsL1x1uY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/6V_DsL1x1uY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```